# JQM selectors collapsible fieldset

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, jquery-selectors

I am using `Jquery mobile` for a form/input fieldset. I need to be able to check if fields in a fieldset are complete/have a value.

When the collapsible gets closed I need to detect if one of all the fields have a value if they don't it should add a class to the collapsible link.

I cannot use the `ID` for the selector as this will go across different sections with various amounts of fieldsets.

My question is am I using the selectors wrong and how can i fix it?

***CODE:***

**JQUERY:**

```
$('a.ui-icon-minus').on('click',function(){
            if($('fieldset:not(.ui-collapsible-collapsed) input[type="radio"]').is(':checked') || $('fieldset:not(.ui-collapsible-collapsed) textarea').val()){
                if($('fieldset:not(.ui-collapsible-collapsed) input[type="radio"]').is(':checked') && $('fieldset:not(.ui-collapsible-collapsed) textarea').val()){
                        $('div.ui-collapsible-heading a').addClass("complete");
                        $('div.ui-collapsible-heading a').removeClass("half-complete");
                        $('div.ui-collapsible-heading a').removeClass("incomplete");
                        alert("complete");
                } else {
                    $('div.ui-collapsible-heading a').addClass("half-complete");
                    $('div.ui-collapsible-heading a').removeClass("incomplete");
                    alert("half-complete");
                }
            } else {
                $('div.ui-collapsible-heading a').addClass("incomplete");
                alert("incomplete");
            }
        });
```

**HTML FIELDSET:**

```
<fieldset data-collapsed="false" data-iconpos="right" data-role="collapsible" id="bc1">
    <div class="ui-collapsible-heading ui-collapsible-heading-collapsed" role="heading">
        <a class="ui-collapsible-heading-toggle ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-btn-inherit ui-icon-plus"href="#">BC1 <span class="ui-collapsible-heading-status">click to expand contents</span></a>
    </div>
    <div aria-hidden="true" class="ui-collapsible-content ui-body-inherit ui-collapsible-content-collapsed">
    <legend>BC1</legend>
        <p>All bank accounts are opened in line with Group Treasury approval.</p>
        <div class="ui-field-contain">
            <label>Control in Place?</label>
            <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
                <input id="bc1-ry" name="bc1" type="radio" value="Y">
                <label for="bc1-ry">Yes</label> <input id="bc1-rn" name="bc1" type="radio" value="N">
                <label for="bc1-rn">No</label>
            </div>
            <label for="bc1-v">Verification</label> 
            <textarea id="bc1-v" name="bc1-v"></textarea>
            <label for="bc1-c">Comments</label> 
            <textarea id="bc1-c" name="bc1-c"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use such an event handler (not tested code):

```
$( ".ui-collapsible" ).on( "collapsiblecollapse", function( event, ui ) {
   var incomplete = false;
   // find all inputs and check them
   $(event.target).find('input,textarea').each(function(idx,ele){
          // here check if the input has valid value
          // e.g.
          incomplete |= $(ele).val()=='';
   })
   // toggle incomplete class on the <a> element
   $('div.ui-collapsible-heading a', $(event.target)).toggleClass('incomplete',incomplete);
} );
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help, the problem with your code is that if the radio and the second text area has a value incomplete will go `true false true` which won't work since its only half complete. see example : https://jsfiddle.net/wyfvck64/9/

Comment: @JamieSterling You mean probably, that different input types need different handling for fetching their values and afterwards more logic is involved in making decision, which class should be applied.  As for first you can make checks on ele inside each loop, whether it's text radio or textarea, pick value, check it and set an external variable like radioValIsOk and then outside the each loop check all the variables and make decision about adding/removing classes

Comment: I have adapted your answer to create a working version. Thanks. See: https://jsfiddle.net/wyfvck64/18/